# How to create funkyradio checkboxes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create checkboxes (like the following) dynamically by using Javascript.

```
<div id="funkyradio">
        <div class="funkyradio-default">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox1" checked/>
            <label for="checkbox1">First Option default</label>
        </div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
someDiv = document.getElementById('funkyradio');

input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'radio';
input.name = 'radio';
input.id = 'radio1';

funkyradio = document.createElement('funkyradio-default');
funkyradio.className = 'funkyradio-default';

label = document.createElement('label');
label.for = 'radio1';
label.value = 'test';

input.appendChild(label);
funkyradio.appendChild(input);
someDiv.appendChild(funkyradio);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ng5wx021/1/

This is how I want them to look like:

[image: I don't have the formatting like here:]

So the problem is not creating them, it's just not using the style from the CSS when I create them with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will render your original HTML (and I have added the CSS of Bootstrap and FunkyRadio):

```js
let funkyradio = document.getElementsByClassName('funkyradio')[0];

let funkyradio_default = document.createElement('div');
funkyradio_default.className = 'funkyradio-default';

let input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'checkbox';
input.name = 'checkbox';
input.id = 'checkbox1';
input.checked = true;
funkyradio_default.appendChild(input);

let label = document.createElement('label');
label.for = 'checkbox1';
label.innerHTML = 'First Option default';
funkyradio_default.appendChild(label);

funkyradio.appendChild(funkyradio_default);
```

```css
.funkyradio div {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.funkyradio label {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty {
  display: none;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty ~ label {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-indent: 3.25em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty ~ label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 2.5em;
  background: #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
  color: #888;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #C2C2C2;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
  color: #777;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:focus ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}

.funkyradio-default input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio-default input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.funkyradio-primary input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

.funkyradio-success input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.funkyradio-danger input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d9534f;
}

.funkyradio-warning input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio-warning input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.funkyradio-info input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio-info input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="funkyradio"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the whole thing into a function and call your function for each instance of your radio button you would like to create!

Remember IDs need to be unique, so use your for loop for that!

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
    CreateRadioButton(i);
}

function CreateRadioButton(index) {
  someDiv = document.getElementById('test');

  input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'radio';
  input.name = 'radio';
  input.id = 'radio' + index;

  funkyradio = document.createElement('funkyradio-default');
  funkyradio.className = 'funkyradio-default';

  label = document.createElement('label');
  label.for = 'radio' + index;
  label.value = 'test';

  input.appendChild(label);
  funkyradio.appendChild(input);
  someDiv.appendChild(funkyradio);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that it's not looking like the ones I create by plain HTML (like here: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Zk2Pz).

Comment: In that example, there is also quite a bit of CSS you need to pick up as well to style the buttons. Are you using the CSS the user provided as well?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm confused why it's not working when I create them with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is an elegant pure JS way and should be working even in old browsers.

```js
let fr = document.createElement('div');
fr.classList.add('funkyradio');

let frd = document.createElement('div');
frd.classList.add('funkyradio-dafault');

let i = document.createElement('input');
i.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
i.setAttribute('name', 'checkbox');
i.setAttribute('id', 'checkbox1');
i.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');

let l = document.createElement('label');
l.setAttribute('for', 'checkbox1');
l.appendChild(document.createTextNode('First option default'));

fr.appendChild(frd);
frd.appendChild(i);
frd.appendChild(l);
document.body.appendChild(fr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using string manipulation. or use a function and do innerHTML. 
Next: The style of the div holding the checkboxes must define the total width.
You can then left float checkboxes and labels into that div. as long as the length of the checkbox &  label is less than the parent div, they will align as you wanted. 
Alternative: if each checkbox is in a div with 100% width. they will align since the div will paint itself as a block level item on the canvas (default).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Checkbox creator</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    input{
    border: 5px solid red;
    margin:10px;
    width: 100px;
    }
    .box_holder{
    width: 101px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="checkbox_container" class="box_holder"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var checkbox_names    = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"];
      var container         = document.getElementById("checkbox_container");

      for (var i = 0; i < checkbox_names.length; i++) {
       var result   = "<input type='checkbox' name='"+ checkbox_names[i] +"'>";
       container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + result; //same as container.innerHTML+=result;
     }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```